# Why is the number of milliseconds between now and 1970 showing as around 800?

Tags: c#

Here is the code I am using. It seems simple but the number it returns is incorrect:

```
var a = DateTime.Now;
var b = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var c = a.Subtract(b);
var d = c.Milliseconds;
return d;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `TotalMilliseconds`, closing as a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Milliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.milliseconds?view=net-5.0) property gives you the milliseconds *component* of the time span (in other words, the millisecond-of-second), not the total number of milliseconds in the timespan. Its magnitude will always be less than 1000, since it's how many milliseconds are left when you have taken all the whole seconds away from the time span.

For what you want, use [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan_TotalMilliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `c.TotalMilliseconds` instead of `c.Milliseconds;`